# Joint probabilities $P(X-Y> \frac{1}{2}) $ Finding the range of Y

Tags: probability

Consider the following joint PDF of $X$ and $Y$ :

$f(x,y) = \frac{1}{2}(x + 3y)$

$0 < x < 1,   0 < y < 1,$

Find $P(X - Y > \frac{1}{2}).$

Solution:

$P(X −Y > \frac{1}{2}) = P(X > \frac{1}{2} + Y,0 < Y < \frac{1}{2}) $

..

..

Why is the range of $Y  :  0 < Y < \frac{1}{2}$ ?
Can someone break down the steps for me, thanks!

Comment: No matter what $X$ is, if $Y > \frac{1}{2}$ then $X-Y < \frac{1}{2}$

Answer (score 1):

$$x>\frac{1}{2}+y$$
but $x$ range is given as

$$0<x<1$$

thus $$1>\frac{1}{2}+y$$
gives us $$\frac{1}{2}>y$$

also $$0<y<1$$

thus $$\frac{1}{2}>y>0$$

Comment: Why is it necessary to look at x range first? Can you explain to me the concept? Thanks a lot!

Comment: it is not necessary to look at x range first you can also look at y range first it is just intersection of two ranges

Comment: I see, thanks a lot!